# php code to load latest posts from a term

Tags: 6, theming

How can I load 10 latest posts from a term using a PHP code, I know how to display latest titles but I need latest nodes body or teaser too.

How is that possible? (title and body)

Comment: Have you tried using Views?

Comment: Thanks, I'm designing a new custom theme and I definitely don't want to use views. is there anyway to do it with node_load() ?

Comment: is it about drupal 6 or 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use [`taxonomy_select_nodes()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/6) to build and run the query for you, it orders by `n.sticky DESC, n.created DESC` by default but you can change that to just `n.created DESC` if you need to by passing the 5th argument to the function.

It also limits the query to the number of records found in the `default_nodes_main` variable, which defaults to 10.

```
$tids = array(1); // 1 is the term id (tid)
$result = taxonomy_select_nodes($tids);

while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $node = node_load($row->nid);

  $title = $node->title;
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Really Thanks Clive, actually when I use extra arguments like LIMIT or posts order it doesn't work. can you make an example?

Comment: oh Thanks again I found the solution: `taxonomy_select_nodes($tids = array(3), $operator = 'or', $depth = 0, $pager = FALSE, $order = 'n.sticky ASC, n.created ASC');`

Comment: sorry a problem came up, when I use this code posts lose  formatting. I mean there is no paragraph anymore. how can I fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Try `$body = check_markup($node->body, $node->format, FALSE);`

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have $tid with your term id:

for drupal 7:

```
$result = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, FALSE, "10", array('t.created' => 'DESC'));
$nodes = array();
foreach($result as $node) {
    $nodes[] = $node;
}
```

for drupal 6:

```
$nids = taxonomy_select_nodes(array($tid), 'or', 0, FALSE, 'n.created DESC LIMIT 0,10');
$nodes = array();
while ($n = db_fetch_object($nids)) {
    $nodes[] = node_load($n->nid);
}
```

I didn't test the code above but I'm sure it should work.

Comment: Nice idea tacking the `LIMIT` on the end of the order clause

Comment: Thanks Alex, I could get latest posts, but I had a problem about extra arguments that commented on Clive's post.